# How to move Zuul gateway configurations to configuration server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I'm starting out with microservices architecture and spring cloud.
I'm trying to get configurations for my Spring Zuul Gateway from the spring configuration server.
I've added below properties in *bootstrap.properties* file of the gateway service:

> spring.application.name=api-gateway
>
> spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
>
> spring.profiles.active=dev

Even though these properties work for all other services, for the gateway they do not work.
The annotations I'm using for the gateway are:

```
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApiGatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiGatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

The annotation for other services is only:

```
@SpringBootApplication
```

My configuration server has a connected git repository with a file: *api-gateway-dev.properties*

logs of gateway:

> :: Spring Boot ::             (v2.3.0.M4)
>
> 2020-04-17 21:42:39.983  INFO 10340 --- [  restartedMain]
>   c.nyo.apigateway.ApiGatewayApplication   : The following profiles are
>   active: dev 2020-04-17 21:42:41.926  WARN 10340 --- [  restartedMain]
>   o.s.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointId     : Endpoint ID
>   'service-registry' contains invalid characters, please migrate to a
>   valid format. 2020-04-17 21:42:41.969  WARN 10340 --- [ 
>   restartedMain] o.s.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointId     : Endpoint ID
>   'hystrix.stream' contains invalid characters, please migrate to a
>   valid format. 2020-04-17 21:42:42.240  INFO 10340 --- [ 
>   restartedMain] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory
>   id=a11a283e-7de6-3470-b177-65c08eab7398 2020-04-17 21:42:43.859  INFO
>   10340 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  :
>   Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8765 (http) 2020-04-17 21:42:43.880 
>   INFO 10340 --- [  restartedMain]
>   o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]

logs of a service that is getting configurations:

> :: Spring Boot ::             (v2.3.0.M4)
>
> 2020-04-17 21:54:01.414  INFO 5180 --- [  restartedMain]
>   c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server
>   at : http://localhost:8888 2020-04-17 21:54:04.184  INFO 5180 --- [ 
>   restartedMain] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Located
>   environment: name=users-service, profiles=[dev], label=null,
>   version=244114f5a11aa7d4a0acb5750ddad144f7de1be5, state=null
>   2020-04-17 21:54:04.186  INFO 5180 --- [  restartedMain]
>   b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source:
>   [BootstrapPropertySource {name='bootstrapProperties-configClient'},
>   BootstrapPropertySource
>   {name='bootstrapProperties-https://my-user@bitbucket.org/my-user/configs.git/users-service-dev.properties'},
>   BootstrapPropertySource
>   {name='bootstrapProperties-https://my-user@bitbucket.org/my-user/configs.git/users-service.properties'}]
>   2020-04-17 21:54:04.197  INFO 5180 --- [  restartedMain]
>   c.n.U.UsersServiceApplication            : The following profiles are
>   active: dev

1. Is it logical to make gateway configuration dynamic?
2. Why don't I get the configuration from the configuration server?

Comment: Yes, it should work. What does not work? There should be log entries trying to connect to config server, can you add those? Can you hit http://localhost:8888/api-gateway/dev?

Comment: I've added logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. I was missing:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config'
```

in my build.gradle file dependencies